# Restricting access to a CloudFoundry-hosted website to a limited number of beta testers

Tags: authentication, spring-security, basic-authentication, cloud-foundry

**I would like to use cloudfoundry to demo a Spring-based webapp to a limited group of beta testers.**

I can't really rely on the application's own authentication/security mechanism **as it is already used by the business logic of the application** (i.e. a visitor to the website can register as a new member and then login with an email and password).

I therefore need some way to restrict access to my beta website to a limited number of beta testers who will need to "pre-authenticate" before they can navigate both the "public" and "private" part of the beta website.

Is this possible with CloudFoundry? If so how?

Answer (score 2):

No, currently it is not possible. As soon as you've published your app to CF and registered a rote for it, it becomes publicly available to all internet users.

The authentication mechanism that CF provides is for management purposes (e.g. creating a user that will be able to push new version of the app to CF) and is not connected with the business logic of your application.

CF only provides abstraction from a hosting platform according to [PaaS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Platform_as_a_service) approach. That means that your app will implement all the functionality it needs, including authentication.

However you could use some standard features of your framework to achieve this, but still you is the one who is responsible for it.